# How to test JavaScript based touch events without having any touch based screen / device?

Tags: javascript, android, touch, mobile-safari, dom-events

How to test touch events without having any touch based screen / device?

I have Windows 7 PC and my monitor is not touch based.

Comment: Do you specifically mean multitouch?

Comment: Are you using any framework, e.g. jQuery Mobile?

Comment: @JoshLee - Yes. Whatever is possible with javascript to go close with native app

Comment: @SimpleCoder - What if i use jQuery Mobile, can i test events without having touch devices?

Comment: Try out the demos on your PC: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/. I'm not sure that events such as 'swipe' will work, but viewing it on your PC should give you a pretty accurate view of what it will look like on a phone.

Comment: @SimpleCoder - I'm not only asking about look. I'm mainly asking for asking to test touch based gestures.

Comment: I know. I'm not sure that you'll be able to use the swipe gestures on a PC

Answer (score 1):

You can use google chrome. Open console by pressing F12 or inspect any element, in right-bottom corner click on gear icon, then go to "overrides" where you can enable "Emulate touch events". Your mouse clicks will be like touches.
Notice: unbind/remove any pc's click events like onclick,onmousedown,.click and .ect because in this mode will works both of touch and click events.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If it's still actual, you can use [this](https://github.com/jtangelder/faketouches.js) library to test touch events. It's used to test touch for Hammer.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to [install the Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html) and use the browser in the emulator. I'd advise an Android 2.x image as emulation is a bit slow, especially the 3.x and 4.0 images.

Answer (score 0):

`Hammer.js` library can simulate touch events on desktop devices.
http://eightmedia.github.com/hammer.js/